# ng options array in object

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an array of object like this:

```
$scope.countries = [{Name: "Taiwan", Cities: ["1","2","3"]}, {Name: "Usa", Cities: ["1","2","3"]}] ;
```

Now iam trying to make ng options on the cities with a filter:

```
<input ng-model="search.Name">
```

And the code thats not working:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="o for o in countries.Cities | filter:search:strict"></select>
```

I managed to make it work with ng repeat and ul li but I have a performance issue because my real array have like 1500-2000 cities for each country..

Comment: i suggest you a combobox, dropdown with autocomplete, calling an http call, for performance, and for usability

Comment: I need to use dropdown without auto complete

Answer (score 0):

If you want to single country cities in select option use this code:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="o for o in countries[**Position**].Cities | filter:search:strict"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="o for o in search.Name.Cities"></select>
```